# Suprabhedāgama Text

Tags: shiva, translation-request, agamas, shaiva-siddhanta

I found one text of Suprabhedāgama, a Shaiva Agama text at https://vedicreserve.miu.edu/sthapatya_veda/suprabhedagama.pdf .

Is there any English/Hindi/Tamil/Telugu translation of it? Or any old manuscript edition of it available?